# Azure Management Rest API Auth token

Tags: api, http, azure, authentication, token

I want to use the Azure Management rest API to start and stop some Virtual Machines.

In the HTTP header I need a Authentication token as described here: [Common parameters and headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163630.aspx#bk_common).
I create a new app in the AD Section of Azure portal and added the auth token to the http header in this format:

```
Authorization : Basic clientID:token
```

where `clientID:token` is base64 encoded, but I am getting this error:

> {"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailedInvalidHeader","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is provided in an invalid format."}}

[REST API - Start a virtual machine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163628.aspx)

Comment: Have you seen this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx?

Comment: Basic is for username/password authentication. Try to use 'Bearer' and a base64 encoded JWT token.

Comment: Why you encode the clientid to base64, did you try use the original clientid and secretkey from app?

Answer (score 1):

After you get the access_token, you should set HTTP Authenticate header like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Basically it would look like a:

```
GET /subscriptions HTTP/1.1
Host: management.core.windows.net
x-ms-version: 2016-04-21
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciO.....o-ZeMSUbOlC4YEw
```

And you can refer to [Microsoft Azure REST API + OAuth 2.0](https://ahmetalpbalkan.com/blog/azure-rest-api-with-oauth2/) for more help. Hope it do help.